# Linux Xampp vhosts issues

Tags: linux, apache, xampp, lampp

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 and xampp and have the following configuration (I've changed the default htdocs folder to a Projects/www):

**/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf:**

```
DocumentRoot "/media/username/Projects/www"
<Directory "/media/username/Projects/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/media/username/Projects/www/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/media/username/Projects/www/myProject/frontend/web/"
    ServerName local-project
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/media/username/Projects/www/myProject/backend/web/"
    ServerName admin.local-project
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/hosts:**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   username-desktop
127.0.0.1   local-project
127.0.0.1   admin.local-project
```

**The Problem:**

All is working fine, but when I have a link from the frontend to the backend for some reason local-project/ is appended after the protocol. For example:

```
http://local-project/:/admin.local-project?userId=7569
```

Any ideas where I'm wrong?

Comment: this is tagged as php because?

Comment: What you're doing isn't generally the best practice. What many people (including myself) do, is specify it as a domain, i.e. `local-project.dev` & `admin.local-project.dev`

Comment: @Darren thanks for the suggestion. I've changed my vhosts as above but still couldn't find what cause the problem from the question.